# Pickit3 overcurrent protection

Tags: current, protection, pickit

The reason for these questions is I'm using these programmers to test a circuit boards with test firmware so I'm trusting the pickit3 to report programming failures without damage to the USB port and the pickit3. *In terms of protection of the devices the best I can hope for is that the programmer to switch off power in under 1ms should there be a high current draw*. Of-course if something strange like the Vpp line shorting somewhere that could send a high voltage to any of the lines.

1. Is it possible to damage a pickit3 or pm3 if powering target from the programmer with 5V?
2. Is current protection bulletproof when there are no external power sources no matter what permutation of fault exists on the target?
3. If current protection works then how long does it take to switch off the power?
4. Will the Pickit3 stop what it's doing no matter when, during programming, if the over-current occurs?

Comment: Could you please breakdown your wall of text into observations, actions, then questions. Your question(s) must make sense if you want an answer. You do have many questions. What are the most important ones?

Comment: I would appreciate a response to any of the questions. The details I gave in subsequent statements and interrogations, from the first question, were to clarify scope of the initial (first) question. I can later construct a data structure, like a tree, from all helpful responses.

Comment: I'd like to break it down in the opposite direction because I want to protect my hardware - pickit3 ( minus the pm3). My action and observation will be to test out the ideas from any feedback.

Comment: I have organized your questions into a much more readable form, putting your observations and requirements first. Please read and understand why it was done this way. Your basic requirements now stand out, as do your questions, making it much easier for someone to answer them.